# Formatting a float value as a percentage in C# is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In `SQL Server 2012 SSMS`, following correctly returns `43.69180299700`. In ASP.NET Core, I want to display it as a percentage `43.69%`. But the `View` shown below returns it wrongly as `4,369.18 %`. **Question**: What I may be missing and how can I correct it in `View`? **Note**: There is no formatting applied via `annotations` in either Model or ViewModel. Both have just attributes of type `float?`.

**T-SQL**:

```
select (386771.20/885226.00)*100
```

**ViewModel**:

```
Public class ProfitViewModel
{
    ....
    public float? val1 { get; set; }
    public float? val2{ get; set; }
    public string profit_percent { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
....
....
ProfitViewModel ProfitVM = new ProfitViewModel();
....
....
float? val1 = 386771.20;
float? val2 = 885226.00;

ProfitVM.profit_percent = ((float)(val1/ val2) * 100).ToString("P");
....
....
return View(ProfitVM);
```

**View**: [Line below displays as 4,369.18 % instead of 43.69%]

```
....
Total Percentage: <div>@Model.profit_percent</div>
....
```

Comment: Formatting as a percentage assumes that 0.73 means "73%".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the "P" format handles the multiplying for you. Try not multiplying by 100

Comment: Your suggestion (and `@adjan`s) worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `* 100` from the line

```
ProfitVM.profit_percent = ((float)(val1/ val2) * 100).ToString("P");
```